# Trying to display API Data in HTML - data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, foreach

Could anyone please take a look, new to API and JavaScript really,

I am trying to display the thumbnail data from the API, however I keep getting the error below,

```
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
    at index.js:9:18
    at async comics (index.js:4:22)
```

Having read and watched a lot trying to figure it out, I thought I'd reach out to see if someone could show me and explain what I'm doing wrong.

currently using vanilla JS and have changed the key for this question, however consle.log shows data, I just cant make it appear in HTML.

```
async function comics() {

    const urlComic = await fetch("https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/comics?limit=100&apikey=85848598594594")
        .then(result => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(comic => {
                const comicBook = `<img src=${comic.thumbnail} >`;

                document.querySelector(".imgContainer").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", comicBook);
            });
        })

        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

comics()
```

I have tried researching as to why this isn't working but can't find the correct solution or tip to help me figure it out.

I am looking to generate the thumbnail data into an `<img>`

Comment: The base of the debugging is to understand the error message. In this case it tells you `data` is not an array (or other object) having `forEach` method. Check what is really returned from the server in the Network tab of the DevTools. (My guess is, that the returned value is parsed to object, not to array, hence the error).